# Swift 5 Remove all AVCaptureSession Inputs

Tags: avcapturesession, swift5

I am trying to remove all inputs and outputs from an avCaptureSession (if there are any) before attempting to add one using:

```
if (avCaptureSession.inputs.count > 0){
        avCaptureSession.inputs.removeAll()
    }else{
        avCaptureSession.addInput(avCaptureInput)
    }
```

But I get a compile error: "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'inputs' is a get-only property"

So how do I remove all inputs?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

```
for input in avCaptureSession.inputs {
        avCaptureSession.removeInput(input);
    }
```